# Adding values returned by SQL query to get the total?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, addition

I have a function that gets the Quantity and Weight of each item for a user's order from a SQL table based on the order id:

```
protected decimal getOrderWeight(int orderid)
{
    string sqlCmd = "SELECT Weight, Quantity FROM OrderItems WHERE OrderId = @OrderId";
    int qty = 0;
    decimal wgt = 0;
    decimal totalWeight = 0;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", orderid);
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Quantity"]);
                wgt = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Weight"]);     
                totalWeight = qty * wgt;
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
    return totalWeight;
}
```

In the table (which is called OrderItems), each item has a quantity and a weight. However, the weight featured in the table is NOT the result of weight * quantity (i.e. item ABC has a quantity of 6 for Order #12345, and each ABC item weighs 1.00 lbs.). The function I created works in that it multiplies each order item's quantity by the weight (i.e. The total weight for all 6 ABC items is 6.00 lbs)

However, I now need to take these total weight values and add them together to get the total weight for the whole order. Right now, I am returning all the weights in an order:
6.00,
5.00,
2.80,
146.76,
6.02,
2.25

But I am not sure how to add all these together? I was thinking of doing a Split() but then I would be converting decimals to strings only to convert them back to decimals to add them together once "split." This seems awfully complicated...is there a better way?

Comment: Would your code not do this if you just changed the calculation line to `totalWeight += qty * wgt;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT sum(Weight * Quantity) as TotalWeight
FROM OrderItems
WHERE OrderId = @OrderId;
```

If so, this is an example of an aggregation query, which is a basic SQL concept.  You should do this type of work in the database, because the database is optimized to work with large volumes of data and extract such results from the tables.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro This would move application logic from code to database, which I think is a bad practice now days.. The best approach IMHO is to have this calculation done in a business layer using LINQ.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. That was much easier than I was thinking it was going to be...Thanks!

Comment: @Oscar I guess, in few cases (like this solution) using `DataBase` is better then loops inside the code or using linq. Because it saves code execution time.

Comment: @Oscar . . . Just suffice it to say that I strongly disagree with you. "Database applications" generally consist of both an application interface and a data store, logic appropriate for each component should go where it best fits.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Why in this case is better? If you use linq you're doing the same, as the calculation will be done in database, but keeping your business's related code in the application domain code.

Comment: @Oscar Taking this case as example, final goal is to get the `total` and not the details, so why to get all the result to the application and then do calculation? instead of just executing same in a query?

Comment: @Bharadwaj If you know how LINQ works then you should know that you don't need to get the data from db to make it in LINQ, just a single line of code can do the same that your transact code, but keeping the logic in the domain model, as I said. 
var sum = dataContext.Sum(x => x.Weight * x.Quantity);

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you sum total weight values like this:
    totalWeight += qty * wgt;

Because now your *totalWeight* will contain total weight value of last item in order only.